# How long does an alien have to fly into Korea once my D-4 visa is issued?

Tags: south-korea

If an alien (i.e. a non South Korean national) applies to a D-4 visa to study in Korea, and assume the visa is granted, is there any pre-defined period of time the alien has since the visa is issued till he can fly in?

i.e. In many countries for many types of visas this is predefined as 3 months. So whenever they grant you the visa, they grant you the next 3 months to "use" it, i.e. meaning to fly into the country for which the visa is issued.

However, I am not sure how that works for D-4 visa for Korea. Has anyone an idea?